# How to get date from a cell and convert the date format?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Spreadheet and Script editor for my work. 
In Column G, i am entering date like 22-May-2019.

But when I am using Logger.Log(row[6]) to check the date, It is showing me date like: Wed May 22 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2019

But I want it to show me 22-05-2019.

Will anybody please help me to get the Code in JavaScript. 
I would be highly obliged

Comment: Be careful in spelling JavaScript, to collide with Java when searching.

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string to a `Date` by using the constructor. Once you have the `Date` object you can call its methods such as `getDate()`, `getMonth()`, and `getFullYear()`. Finally you can use [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to format and print the string:

```js
function getFormattedDate(s) {
  var d = new Date(s);
  var date = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = d.getFullYear();

  if (date < 10) {
    date = "0" + date;
  }

  if (month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month;
  }

  return `${date}-${month}-${year}`;
}

//Your string
var s = '22-May-2019';

console.dir(getFormattedDate(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to format the date like this, but I don't know if the Google spreadsheet API can handle it:

`Logger.Log((new Date(row[6])).toDateString())`

You can look for this `toDateString` method of the JavaScript Date object here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString